# node.js express-winston errorLogger skip doesn't work

Tags: node.js, express, winston

I'm using node.js with express-winston for logging, like that:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var winston = require('winston');
var expressWinston = require('express-winston');

var routes = require('./routes/index');

app.use("/", routes);

app.use(
    expressWinston.errorLogger({
        transports: [
            new winston.transports.DailyRotateFile({
                name: 'file',
                datePattern: '_dd-MM-yyyy.log',
                colorize: true,
                json: true,
                filename: './logs/errors/error_log',
                maxsize: 50 * 1024 * 1024,
                maxFiles: 10,
                zippedArchive: true
            }),
            new winston.transports.Console({
                json: true,
                colorize: true
            })
        ],
        skip: function(req, res) {
            return true;
        }
    })
);
```

Notice that I'm using the skip function and returning true (for test purpose) in order to skip all error logging like written here: [express-winston options](https://github.com/bithavoc/express-winston#options)

but it doesn't work, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

the `skip` function is called after response has been sent as per the [README.md](https://github.com/bithavoc/express-winston#options):

> A function to determine if logging is skipped, defaults to returning false. Called *after* response has already been sent.

For your example you want to use the `ignoreRoute` option which for your case would be a function that returns `true`.

> A function to determine if logging is skipped, defaults to returning false. Called *before* any later middleware.

```
app.use(
  expressWinston.errorLogger({
    transports: [
        new winston.transports.DailyRotateFile({
            name: 'file',
            datePattern: '_dd-MM-yyyy.log',
            colorize: true,
            json: true,
            filename: './logs/errors/error_log',
            maxsize: 50 * 1024 * 1024,
            maxFiles: 10,
            zippedArchive: true
        }),
        new winston.transports.Console({
            json: true,
            colorize: true
        })
    ],
          v------------------------------ use `ignoreRoute` instead of `skip`
    ignoreRoute: function(req, res) {
        return true;
    }
  })
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are registering Winston middleware after route middleware. You have to register it first before executing route middleware.

Correct implementation -

```
const routeWhitelist = [
  "/route/whitelisted",
];

app.use(expressWinston.logger({
  ignoreRoute: function (req, res) {
    return routeWhitelist.indexOf(req.path) === -1;
  },
  skip: function (req, res) {
    return res.statusCode == 200;
  },
  winstonInstance: logger
})
);

app.use("/", routes);
```

Pointers to note - 
`ignoreRoute` - Called before any later middleware. `res` object will have wrong data. 
`skip` - Called after response has already been sent. `res` object will have correct data.